# No Windows after installing Kali

Tags: linux, windows, kali-linux, grub2, dual-boot

Yesterday I installed Kali, however, after the install had finished there were no bootable operating systems. Neither my Windows 10 or Kali would launch.

After reading around I found a repair boot, made a live CD, and "fixed"  grub. This allowed me to launch my Kali OS but it still would not let me launch my Windows 10. Here is the [PasteBin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23415946/)

This brings me to a few hours ago. Since then I have not been able to fix my system so it launches Win10. I can mount my hard drive that had my Win10 OS on and that was not touched during Kali setup, I have tried the methods [here (except manually writing an entry)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows).

I have also tried booting on the HDD that has the partition for Win10 but that provides me with a black screen and a flashing white line. The same result that I had before I ran boot repair and got Kali to work. I read it my be related to secure boot but that is disabled.

So I am asking how can I boot into windows, either by booting onto the hard drive that contains it or adding it to the Grub Kali launches of?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out if your Windows booted through UEFI or the MBR. Newer Windows installations, especially machines that came with Windows 10 may boot through a UEFI partition.

If Kali installed through traditional MBR / Grub, you may have lost the boot to UEFI partition.

You could try the bootable thumb drive that Windows provides.. you may have to find another Windows machine to make it though: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool

Comment: If that is so how do I regain the ability to boot to the UEFI partion

Comment: Try making the boot drive. I just added a link. No guarantees.

Comment: OOPS. Use this link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17422/windows-8-create-usb-recovery-drive or equivalent windows

Comment: For 10: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/3a747883-b706-43a5-a286-9e98f886d490/create-a-recovery-drive

Answer (score 0):

I tried below solution when i came across same situation (Ubuntu and windows 8 in my case)

Insert windows10 USB/CD and Fix bootloader of Windows using below commands -

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
```

And then try to run windows 10, it will work but you won't be able to see Kali.
Once Windows is fixed you need to insert Kali USB/CD to install grub .

```
fdisk -l
sudo mount /dev/sdXX /mnt
update-grub
grub-install /dev/sdX
sudo umount /mnt
```

Now the default boot loader will be grub but you will be able to see two entry over there one for kali and another one is for Windows 10.